# Building same directory structure of git server and bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have two environments, one BitBucket and the second a regular git server used with git-shell.

Problem is - I want to use one link for all ENVs

In order to use the same URL and I manipulate the host via /etc/hosts.

Example

```
# /etc/hosts
# ENV X
my-git-repo.com <bitbucket.com>

# ENV Y
my-git-repo.com <personal server.com>
```

And it works fine when I use the domain in all ENVs:

```
git clone ssh://my-git-repo.com/.... .git
```

My problem remains - is the structure between the two providers

```
# Structure of BitBucket
ssh://my-git-repo.com/projectKey/needed_repo.git
                         ^^^

# Structure of git server has no "projectKey"
ssh://my-git-repo.com/needed_repo.git
```

The fact that the URL is different still making me juggling with ENV variables and all kinds of hacks to understand in which ENV i am and then change the address.
Yet, I want a single URL for all.

Question: how i adjust git server directory structure to be the same as BitBucket ?
this way the link is identical ?
Or any other idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a regular git server used with git-shell.

It depends on the actual nature of your git server, but a straightforward approach would be to said local Git server to serve your repository from the `projectKey` subfolder.

Meaning, you would move your existing `needed_repo.git` from the root folder server by your Git server, to a new `projectKey` subfolder.

---

> But in a "configuration level" it just not working ... something between the combination of authorized_keys and `.git` project and the way the interact: just keeps failing.

Adjusting the server's directory structure is one thing, but making sure SSH and the Git services respect and function with the new structure is another challenge.

First, make sure you have the proper configuration in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
If you are using something like `git-shell`, then your `authorized_keys` might look like:

```
command="git-shell -c \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...
```

The `git-shell` ensures that only Git commands can be executed over the SSH connection.

Second, double-check the directories (including the new `projectKey` ones) and the repositories inside them have the correct permissions.   Typically, they should be owned by the `git` user (or whatever user your Git service runs as).

```bash
chown -R git:git /path/to/repositories
```

Those checks allow you to test SSH directly:

```bash
ssh git@my-git-repo.com git-receive-pack 'projectKey/needed_repo.git'
```

(check the logs at `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`)

If there is an issue with the SSH setup, that `ssh` command should help you pinpoint it.

---

If nothing works, consider using [gitolite instead](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)

Gitolite allows you to define repositories in its configuration with a namespace structure. For instance, you can easily set up repositories under different "`projectKeys`" just like BitBucket.

In your Gitolite config, you would have entries like:

```
repo projectKey1/needed_repo
RW+ = @all

repo projectKey2/another_repo
RW+ = @all
```

The above would correspond to directories like `projectKey1/needed_repo.git` in the Gitolite home directory.

With Gitolite in place, when you point `my-git-repo.com` to your personal Git server, your clone URL would look the same as BitBucket's:

```
ssh://git@my-git-repo.com/projectKey1/needed_repo.git
```

While Gitolite does not directly make your BitBucket and personal server URLs identical, it provides the tools and configurations to set up your personal server in such a way that its URL structure matches BitBucket's, making it easier for you to use the same URLs by manipulating `/etc/hosts` as you initially intended.

Comment: Yes that was my thought, but in a "configuration level" it just not working ... something between the combination of authorized_keys and .git project and the way the interact ... just keeps failing

Comment: I highly appreciate it @VonC we are actually using gitolite, I had no idea about `repo projectKey1/needed_repo` !! I'll try it out ! just wanted to mention that I actually tried the first snippet that you wrote, but running `git clone ssh://domain.com/...` the slash caused it to search in the `/` root folder, meaning only `git clone ssh://domain.com/home/$user/repos/needed_repo.git` - but i'll try the gitolite thing !

Comment: @RickyLevi `/` root folder? That would happen with SSH (no Gitolite or forced command), using a key registered in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Surely, you are not using the remote `root` user with your SSH queries?

Comment: no no, it just go to the root and say no permissions ... it's like it doesn't start from the root folder of the home user - it starts from the root folder of the machine itself, maybe the `command=` doesn't work correctly in my case

Comment: @RickyLevi OK. The Gitolite approach might be safer then.

Comment: Tested gitolite conf as you said - and it worked. many thanks !